Как запомнить число и потом его выдать
как мне сделать запоминание, и потом выдачу числа в сообщение?
Сейчас опишу подробнее, у меня есть див, в который и вводится число, так же есть 3 кнопки, 1 кнопка - цифра 3(для примера) 2 кнопка - цифра 8, и 3 кнопка - это запоминание(После её нажатия число сбрасывается до 0).
Мне нужно, что бы после нажатия на кнопку, число что было на диве очистилось, но запомнилось например в number.innerHTML, и каком либо действии с number.innerHTML мне выдавало данное число(Но при каждом нажатии на конпку 3, запоминало новое число)
Вот код(без первых 2 кнопок, так как с ними у меня проблем нет):
Html,js
<div id="display">0</div>
<button class="button" id="button" onclick="Button()"></button>
<button class="button2" id="button2" onclick="Button2()"></button>

let display = document.querySelector("display");

function Button() {
   display.innerText = number.innerHTML;
      if (display.innerText > 0) {
         display.innerText = "0";
 }
}
function Button2() {
   alert(number.innerHTML);
}

Я понимаю, что это полная ересь, но прошу не бить палками, это я накидал для примера



const display = document.querySelector(".display");
    const displayValue = display.innerHTML;
    const saveBtn = document.querySelector(".save");
    const restoreLastValue = document.querySelector(".restore-last-value");

    const LAST_DISPLAY_VALUE = "LAST_DISPLAY_VALUE";
    const INITIAL_VALUE = "0";

    let lastDisplayValue = "";

    saveBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      //засунуть в localStorage
      // localStorage.setItem(LAST_DISPLAY_VALUE, displayValue);
      //просто сахранить в константу
      lastDisplayValue = displayValue;
      display.innerHTML = INITIAL_VALUE;

      //также все значения сахранять в массив
      //также можно засунуть в url
      //также можно отправить на бек для сахранения
      //также можно создать тег и засунуть туда
      //также много чего (просто не понятна цель)
    });

    restoreLastValue.addEventListener("click", () => {
      //достать из localStorage
      // localStorage.getItem(LAST_DISPLAY_VALUE);
      //взять из константы
      display.innerHTML = lastDisplayValue;
    });
    <div class="display">33</div>
    <button class="save">save</button>
    <button class="restore-last-value">restore</button>



